# Facebook shows <p> tag in gatsby blog post description

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I share a blog post link on facebook, the auto generator preview shows the P tag in the description. How can i fix it? My Seo is very messy on google, dont index all pages and social networks. I need help. I'm following as a guideline from the official Gatsby website.

blog post seo props:

```js
<Seo title={data.post.title}
  description={data.post.excerpt} />
```

[image]

Seo component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

const SEO = ({ title, description, image, article }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(query)

  const {
    defaultTitle,
    titleTemplate,
    defaultDescription,
    siteUrl,
    defaultImage,
    twitterUsername
  } = site.siteMetadata

  const seo = {
    title: title || defaultTitle,
    description: description || defaultDescription,
    image: `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`,
    url: `${siteUrl}${pathname}`
  }

  return (
    <Helmet title={seo.title} titleTemplate={titleTemplate}>
      <meta name="description" content={seo.description} />
      <meta name="image" content={seo.image}
      />

      {seo.url && <meta property="og:url" content={seo.url} />}

      {(article ? true : null) && <meta property="og:type" content="article" />}

      {seo.title && <meta property="og:title" content={seo.title} />}

      {seo.description && (
        <meta property="og:description" content={seo.description} />
      )}

      {seo.image && <meta property="og:image" content={seo.image} />}

      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />

      {twitterUsername && (
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content={twitterUsername} />
      )}

      {seo.title && <meta name="twitter:title" content={seo.title} />}

      {seo.description && (
        <meta name="twitter:description" content={seo.description} />
      )}

      {seo.image && <meta name="twitter:image" content={seo.image} />}

      <html lang="pt-BR" />
    </Helmet>
  )
}

export default SEO

SEO.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string,
  article: PropTypes.bool
}

SEO.defaultProps = {
  title: null,
  description: null,
  image: null,
  article: false,
  lang: 'pt-BR'
}

const query = graphql`
  query SEO {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        defaultTitle: title
        titleTemplate
        defaultDescription: description
        siteUrl: siteUrl
        defaultImage: image
        twitterUsername
        
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: So in your `data.post.excerpt` there is some HTML?

Comment: Does only apply to Facebook?

Comment: Hi Ferran, so far only on Facebook.  Link to my graphql https://imgur.com/zthD3vO